# How to send data via BLE using ionic 3 and angular 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

my 1st question here.

I'm currently using **cordova-plugin-ble-central** plugin to send datas over my BLE device. I can't really understand how send data.

What i should do is to send a group of 8 bytes string using an Unit8Array.

this is an example of what i've to send :

```
  array: string[] = [
    '10111010',
    '00000000',
    '00000000',
    '0',
    '00000000',
    '0000',
    '0000',
    '0',
    '0',
    '0000'
]
```

And this is what i'm trying right now :

```
stringToBytes(strings: any[]) {
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(144);
    var array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let string of strings) {
        // console.log('string from 1st for : ', string);
        for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; i++) {
            // console.log('string from 2nd for : ', string);
            array[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
        }
    }
    console.log(array.buffer, 'array : ', array);
    return array.buffer;
}
```

Is this che correct way? Any suggestion?

Sorry for the bad english and if the question has some errors.

Thanks in advice,
Giorgio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off I *strongly* suggest using the [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) wrappers for cordova plugin [`Bluetooth Serial`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial/).

### 1. Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/bluetooth-serial
```

### 2. After installing the plugin’s package, add it to your app’s NgModule.

```js
...

import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    BluetoothSerial,
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### 3. Usage

```js
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial';

constructor(private bluetoothSerial: BluetoothSerial) { }


// Write a string
this.bluetoothSerial.write('hello world').then(success, failure);

// Array of int or bytes
this.bluetoothSerial.write([186, 220, 222]).then(success, failure);

// Typed Array
var data = new Uint8Array(4);
data[0] = 0x41;
data[1] = 0x42;
data[2] = 0x43;
data[3] = 0x44;
this.bluetoothSerial.write(data).then(success, failure);

// Array Buffer
this.bluetoothSerial.write(data.buffer).then(success, failure);
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the fast answer.
I've already used this plugin but i wasn't able to find active BLE devices. Is that normal?
Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: My answer covers `Bluetooth Serial`. This is different than `BLE`. Check it out, it will work for you.

Comment: Maybe i've solved declaring and populating directly one Uint8Array, instead of trying to convert an Array of String into an Array of Byte.

Now i've another question. If i want to send a name i must send the ASCII code of every single letter? The ASCII-to-Letter conversion it's up  to the device that recive the datas?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In Bluetooth protocol it's all  raw bytes being transmitted.